# SQL Performing a search/replace search

Tags: sql, mysql, string, full-text-search

I need to search a specific column for every occurrence of a string and replace it with a different string. The column is a MySQL TEXT column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/04/23/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-mysql-database-using-sql/

```
update TABLE_NAME 
set FIELD_NAME = replace( FIELD_NAME, 
                          ‘find this string’, 
                          ‘replace found string with this string’);
```

Answer (score 0):

The query David Stratton gave would be my answer too. If few of the table's rows contain the search term, you could add a WHERE clause to speed things along.